# GRPC Dll extension file not being found by PHP on local machine

Tags: php, dll, google-ads-api

The below output appears in my CMD (windows 10) after installing ([guide here](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc)):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc' (tried: C:\php\ext\grpc (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_grpc.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc' (tried: C:\php\ext\grpc (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_grpc.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

; Notes for Windows environments :
;
; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
;   extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
;extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
extension=grpc
```

I've downloaded the correct DLL version (x64) for the right PHP version (7.4) and I can even click the location cmd tries when I run it in VS code which just opens the DLL its telling me I don't have. I've also included the extension section from my php.ini as im absoltuely at a loss at this point.

Comment: The guide you're linking to says `extension=php_grpc.dll`.

Comment: the error doesn't change if I do that, the problem remains the same except the output shows it as looking for \php_php_grpc.dll.dll as 7+ php versions dont need the extra parts.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using Thread safe instead of Non thread safe, problem closed.